# JQUERY Image slider

Tags: jquery, css, html

Hey I'm looking to do a simple jquery image slider with a simple dropdown when you click on each of the images,if anybody could help me it would be a lifesaver as i'm not great and still learning html and jquery.So far the code I have is this

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type'/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="eventspage.css" />
        <title>Events page</title>
        <style>
            img {
                float:left;
            }
            .container {
                width:60%;
                margin
            }
            #slider {
                width:400px;
                background-color:green;
                height:200px;
            }
            div {
                position:absolute;
            }
            .window {
                width:400px;
                height:400px;
                overflow:hidden;
                background-color: aqua;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <button id="left">left</button> <button id="right">right</button>

            <div class="window">
                <div id="slider" class="block">
                    <img width="200px" src="person1.jpg">
                    <img width="200px" src="person2.jpg">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>      

        <script>
            $("#right").click(function(){
                $(".block").animate({"left": "+=100px"}, "slow");
            });

            $("#left").click(function(){
                $(".block").animate({"left": "-=100px"}, "slow");
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For the dropdown part of your question:

You could do this by adding a jquery event handler on the images

```
$("#slider img").click(function() {
  //CODE TO OPEN THE DROPDOWN
});
```

Answer (score -1):

[jQuery Cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) is the de-facto jQuery image slider plugin that basically does it all.

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by the dropdown, but it's probably easy to implement on top of Cycle.